# << operator in objective c enum?

Tags: objective-c, operators

I was looking for something and got in to this enum is apple UITableViewCell.h.

I am sorry if this is trivial but I wonder/curious  what is the point of this.

I know the << from ruby but I don't really understand this enum ?

```
enum {
    UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask                     = 0,
    UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask          = 1 << 0,
    UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask   = 1 << 1
};
```

Thanks

**BTW**
Found it as a great way to learn coding, I am trying once in a day to get into the header files of at list on object.

Shani

Comment: Looks like bit-shift (c code).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are bit-field flags. They are used because you can combine them using the bitwise-OR operator. So for example you can combine them like

```
(UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
```

They work by having one bit set in an integer. In this example, in binary,

```
UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask        = 0000 0001
UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask = 0000 0010
```

When they are OR'ed together, they produce `0000 0011`. The framework then knows that both of these flags are set.

The `<<` operator is a left-shift. It shifts the binary representation. So `1 << 1` means

```
0000 0001 shifted left by one bit = 0000 0010
```

`1 << 2` would equal `0000 0100`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why not use 1 and 2 instead ?

Comment: You could use 1,2,4,8,16 instead, but 1,2,3,4,5 don't work because their binary representations overlap

Answer (score 4):

Its actually BItwise shift operator

```
<<  Indicates the bits are to be shifted to the left.
>>  Indicates the bits are to be shifted to the right.
```

So in your statement the value of 1  << 0 is 1 and 1 << 1 is 2

Comment: You have copied this text from [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fbitshe.htm) which is against [IBM's terms of service](http://www.ibm.com/legal/us/en/). In other words: copying the text is a copyright infringement. Please do not copy text from other sources like that. Instead, please link to the page instead. So please edit your answer and remove the copied text. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common trick in C to use the bitwise shift operator in enum values to allow you to combine enumeration values with the bitwise or operator.

That piece of code is equivalent to

```
enum {
    UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask                     = 0,
    UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask          = 1, // 01 in binary
    UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask   = 2  // 10 in binary
};
```

This allows you to bitwise `or` two or more enumeration constants together

```
 (UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) // == 3 (or 11 in binary)
```

to give a new constant that means both of those things at once.  In this case, the cell is showing both an editing control and a delete confirmation control, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

These operand called bitshift. Bitshift operand can be preferred for
   2 reasons.
     - For fast operation
     - Use multiple bool value in one time.

For example : 1<<2 is a left shift; that means 
1 : 0001,
2 : 0010

1 << 2 this line means is 2 should be left one bit. As a result 0010 shifted to 0100

Also shifted value must ordered as a 1,2,4,8,16...

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(int, EntityEngineer) {
EntityEngineeriOS = 1 << 0,
EntityCategoryAndroid = 1 << 1,
EntityCategoryDB = 1 << 2,
EntityCategoryTeamLead = 1 << 16,};
```

Now, we want to check mutiple boolean in below line,

```
char engineer = (EntityEngineeriOS | EntityCategoryAndroid);
```

char 0011 = (0001 | 0010);

```
if (engineer & EntityEngineeriOS) {
    NSLog(@"we are looking for a developer who can write objective c or java");
}

if (engineer & EntityCategoryDB) {
    NSLog(@"we are not looking for a DB manager");
}
```

Result : we are looking for a developer who can write objective c or java

Answer (score 1):

That is the bitshift operator.  That is used commonly for objects that may have multiple behaviors (each enum being a behavior).

Here is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176149/multiple-value-enum-in-obj-c) that may clarify it better.

Answer (score 1):

These types of operator are called bitwise operator which operates on bit value of a number. These operation are very fast as compared to other arithematic operations.